# How to handle null data from JSON

Tags: php, json

I need to handle a null JSON request, just in case the user goofs.

Here's my code:

```
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

//Puts the JSON var into a parameter that actually does the decoding into JSON
$data = json_decode($JSON,true);

echo $JSON;
if ($JSON === ''){

header("Location: contact2.php");

}else{
//Execute the original plan 
}
```

Here's the array of fun if statements that unfortunately haven't worked for me:

```
if(is_array($data))

if($JSON === null)

if($data === null)
```

Greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Explain why it hasn't work. Any eny error message?

Comment: I'm relatively new to PHP, if I had or knew of a decent IDE with a debugger, I would be overall a happier man with less problems. From my understating, the json_decode method throws it into an array. I'm surprised the is_array method didn't work for me when I purposely crashed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check for `empty` of array ,please refer the link
https://www.php.net/empty

Comment: would you happen to know why my header won't redirect locally when the if statement is true? I got the if statement working, it's just the header won't redirect back to the previous forum. Appreciate any help.

Comment: try removing this line echo $JSON; and check

Comment: or would I need to check the JSON data on the forum, before it goes to the next page?

Comment: not able to understand your question ,please explain clear or provide code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP >= 5.3 you can use `json_last_error` to determine if the decode was successful:

```
if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
   // decoded fine
} else {
   // error decoding json
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using gettype

```
if ( gettype(json_decode($data))=='NULL' ){
    //error handler here
}
```